# Какой список библиотек автоматически скачивает Maven

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, зависимости

Всем добрый день.
На локальной машине у меня репозиторий Maven расположен тут:
**K:\Kes\Java\m2\repository**

1. Я самостоятельно удалю содержимое этого каталога
2. Создаю пустой проект Maven
3. Жму:

[image: Скриншот]
4. После этого вижу, что содержимое **K:\Kes\Java\m2\repository** наполнилось кучей библиотек.

Почему они скачались? Как управлять этим списком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
Даже при пустом maven-проекте необходима работа maven-плагинов.
Они в любом случае скачиваются сюда: **\m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins**
При этом можно полностью зачистить репозиторий maven. И затем "двойным щелчком" запустить только один плагин. Например, **clean**. В этот момент зависимости скачаются автоматически именно для этого плагина.
После этого можно глянуть в:
**m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.5\maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom**
Зависимости, которые автоматически подтянул для себя плагин.

Если же мы нажимаем кнопку **Reload All Maven Projects** , которая указана в вопросе на скрине (кнопка "две стрелки"), то у нас автоматически скачиваются все плагины и скачивают за собой все зависимости. Как раз эти зависимости и предоставляют из себя тот набор библиотек, которые подтягиваются для пустого проекта.